# Difference between "struct foo*" and "foo*" where foo is a struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

In C, is there a difference between writing "struct foo" instead of just "foo" if foo is a struct?

For example:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
struct sockaddr *sa;

// Are these two lines equivalent?
sa = (struct sockaddr*)&sin;
sa = (sockaddr*)&sin;
```

Thanks /Erik

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact, in standard "C" it's required to specify `struct` keyword. This is optional in C++.

This is the reason some people define structs like this:

```
typedef struct foo { ... } bar;
```

to be able to use `bar` instead of `struct foo`. However, some C compilers do not enforce this rule.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In C (as opposed to C++), structs are in their own namespace. So if you defined a

```
struct sockaddr { ... }
```

you may not use it as

```
sockaddr s;
sockaddr *ps;
```

In order to make that legal, you may use typedef in order to import into the non-struct namespace of type names:

```
typedef struct sockaddr { ... } sockaddr;
sockaddr s, *p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just "foo" if you typedef it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the struct is defined. If it is defined using a typedef you dont have to put the stuct keyword in front.

```
typedef struct 
{
//
} aStruct;

aStruct abc;
```

but if its not a typedef you need the struct keyword.

```
struct aStruct
{
//
} ;

struct aStruct abc;
```